# Random Value Generator

Tags: arcpy, random

I have a python code where I am trying to assign a unique, random value to every row. I have tried:

```
maxvalue = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(shape).getOutput(0)) + 10000
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(shape, fields="FID"):
     insert = randint(0, maxvalue)
     arcpy.CalculateField_management(shape, "RNDM", '"' + str(insert) + '"', "VB")
```

but to no avail. I keep getting only 1 value for all rows. I have looked at other resources, but the answer still eludes me (e.g. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/96917). This method is as well extremely slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as mentioned by @George, the randint takes a sample with repetition. If you want unique values, create a list of the required size and shuffle it.

```
import random, arcpy
listUnique = range(maxvalue)
random.shuffle(listUnique)
i=0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featureClass,[fieldToUpdate]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        i=i+1
        row[0] = listUnique[i]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am getting NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined.. as part of the for row.

Comment: I've edited my line of code, there was a typo

Comment: +1. Another approach would simply be `cursor.updateRow([listUnique.pop()])` -- no need to increment a counter!

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is happening because you are using the CalculateField tool every time in the loop. So, it will keep the last value of the random value for all rows.

I'm not so sure about the syntax, but it should be something like that:

```
for r in arcpy.UpdateCursor(shape):
    new_value = randint(0, max_value)
    r.setValue(field_name, new_value)
    cursor.UpdateRow(r)
```

Where:

- field_name should be a string, the name of the field you want to update;
- all the other variables should be defined as you already are;

#### EDIT

Check the docs. It asks for field name instead of field index:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000008n000000

The mistakes:

- Using a search cursor for updating a row;
- Using a geoprocessing toolbox to calculate that field value, for **each row**. You basically were calling CalculateFields for each feature or row you had;

This should run much faster and without erros.

### Attention

This does not guarantee that the random values will be unique. Several calls to randint can yield duplicate values.

For proof, try this script here (https://repl.it/B3Tm):

```
from random import randint
min = 0  
max = 1000000
a = []
int_count = {}
for x in range(1,1000000):
    random_value = randint(min, max)
    if random_value in int_count:
        int_count[random_value] = int_count[random_value] + 1
    else:
        int_count[random_value] = 1

print int_count
```

List of results (duplicate results have a count > 1 and just a tiny snippet)

> {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 1, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 1,
>   14: 1, 18: 2, 19: 1, 20: 1, 24: 1, 25: 3, 26: 1, 27: 2, 28: 1, 31: 1,
>   32: 1, 33: 1, 34: 1, 35: 2, 36: 2, 37: 1, 38: 2, 40: 2, 41: 2, 42: 1,
>   44: 1, 45: 1, 46: 3, 47: 2, 49: 1, 50: 2, 52: 1, 53: 1, 54: 1, 55: 1,
>   56: 2, 57: 1, 59: 3, 60: 1, 61: 1, 63: 2, 64: 1, 66: 1, 69: 1, 71: 1,
>   72: 2, 74: 1, 75: 1, 79: 1, 80: 1, 84: 1, 86: 2, 87: 1, 88: 2, 90: 2,
>   91: 2, 94: 1, 95: 2, 96: 1, 98: 1, 100: 1, 101: 1, 102: 1, 103: 1,
>   105: 1, 106: 1, 107: 1, 112: 2, 113: 1, 114: 2, 115: 1, 116: 1, 117:
>   1, 118: 2, 119: 1, 120: 2, 122: 2, 124: 1, 126: 2, 127: 1, 130: 1,
>   131: 2, 133: 1, 138: 1, 139: 3, 140: 1, 141: 1, 143: 2, 144: 1, 145:
>   2, 146: 1, 148: 2, 149: 2, 151: 3, 152: 1, 153: 2, 154: 1

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is what I am looking for. I am getting an error however

r[27] = new_value
TypeError: 'Row' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Have you changed your cursor to be an UpdateCursor? Oh sorry, it looks like you have to use the following syntax for the updateCursor: row.setValue(field_index, new_value) Try that, if that works, I'll update the answer.

Comment: New error: in setValue
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.SetValue(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.